# How to import issues from repo or organization into github project?

Tags: github, github-projects

I want to use [Github projects](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-27-the-new-github-issues-public-beta/) to triage issues from a repo. Problem is how to load all issues from repo into github project that I have created?

I have seen couple of videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI1ra-XHWHM&t=2s) one but everyone is creating issues manually in Project or adding references manually which is not possible for repo with many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs -- https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/managing-items-in-your-project/adding-items-to-your-project#bulk-adding-issues-and-pull-requests

The steps for adding issues in bulk lets you add 25 at a time. If you have far more than e.g. 100 issues, then probably you need to do a lot of triage before trying to put them all on a board.

Important: *use filters* in the bulk add process. By default it shows you *all* issues and PRs that aren't already on the board. Do you just want **open** issues, and not PRs? Then filter on "is:issue is:open" before adding.